# Iteratively appending links to a D3 force directed network visualization

Tags: javascript, networking, d3.js, visualization, force-layout

I'm a beginner in javascript/d3, and came across a great [network visualization](http://dhs.stanford.edu/dh/networks/) I wanted to play around with.

I am looking to make the visualization dynamic, by adding links and their associated nodes at specified times.

To get me started, I first tried to keep all nodes displayed and simply add the links as they appear in the data file.

Stripping down the [original html](https://gist.github.com/emeeks/4588962) file, here is my attempt (adding the iterateLink() function, and slightly tweaking initializeGraph() ):

```
function iterateLinks() {
  for ( x = 0; x < zlinkz.length; x++ ) {
    setTimeout( function() {

      links.push(zlinkz[x]);
      restart();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

function initializeGraph(newGraph) {
  newNodes = [];
  newLinks = [];
  // We need a hash to fit the link structure of D3's force-directed layout
  nodeHash = {};

  zlinkz   = [];

  for ( x = 0; x < newGraph.nodes.length; x++ ) {
    newNodes.push(newGraph.nodes[x]);
    nodeHash[String(newGraph.nodes[x].id)] = x;
  }

  for ( x = 0; x < newGraph.links.length; x++ ) {
    newLinks.push({id: x, source: newGraph.nodes[nodeHash[newGraph.links[x].source]], target: newGraph.nodes[nodeHash[newGraph.links[x].target]], "cost": newGraph.links[x].cost, "weight": newGraph.links[x].invcost });
  }

  force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(newNodes) // initialize with a single node
      .links(newLinks)
      .linkDistance(60)
      .charge(-60)
      .on("tick", tick);

  var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("id", "networkViz");

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("id","backgroundRect")
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  nodes = force.nodes();
  links = force.links();
  node = svg.selectAll(".node");
  link = svg.selectAll(".link");
  arrowhead = svg.selectAll(".link");

  cursor = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)")
      .attr("class", "cursor")
      .attr("r", 1)
      .style("opacity", 0);

  restart();
  iterateLinks();
}
```

The complete code can be found on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28q4G/5/).

The function doesn't seem to iterate through the links despite my iterateLinks() function and doesn't display the links.

Do you know where I'm going wrong with the function, and how to solve it?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks.

===== EDIT =====

Thanks to @Barnab and @AmeliaBR's help, I made the changes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/28q4G/12/) and also included the adding nodes dynamically too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things :

- In your `iterateLinks` the `x` variable goes from 0 to 2 before the function in `setTimeout` is called, resulting in pushing always `zlinkz[3]` instead of your desired range of 0 to 2. I fixed it this way and it works the way you probably wanted it to :

  ```
  var it = 0;
  for (x = 0; x < zlinkz.length; x++) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          links.push(zlinkz[it]);
          restart();
          it++;
      }, 2000);
  }
  ```
- There seems to be something wrong with your `arrowhead` drawing. I commented it out in this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28q4G/6/) and if I understood what its function is I might be able to help you debug it :) If you uncomment it you'll see your links and nodes connected disappear because of a problem with `.getElementById('directedCheck').checked`

PS : I have written a tutorial on dynamic force-layout visualization on [my blog](http://blablarnab.com/wordpress/2013/11/23/dynamic-d3-js-with-a-simple-caterpillar-example/) and maybe it can give you some ideas for future endeavours.

Comment: Also, you were probably intending to have each link added individually; to do that, make your setTimeout time parameter `2000*x` (note that in this case, x would be evaluated at the time the timer is started, not when the function is executed, so it would be different for each round of the `for` loop).  You could also do the same thing slightly more efficiently with `setInterval` instead, see http://jsfiddle.net/28q4G/7/

Comment: thank you for this @Barnab and @AmeliaBR! I made the changes you recommended (see http://jsfiddle.net/28q4G/11/) and made the nodes appear dynamically too but the visualization is very shaky. Do you know why that is? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I found it was because I added the same nodes repetitively. Changes are here: http://jsfiddle.net/28q4G/12/